# Finding controls by name in .NET 1.1 forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-1.1, legacy-code, visual-studio-2003

I'm working on some legacy WindowsForms application written in VB.NET using the framework 1.1 and I'm trying to retrieve a control from the ControlCollection using its name instead of his index.

In the following versions of the framework I can use the Find() method but it seems that in 1.1 it's not available. I wrote a while statement that loops the entire ControlCollection until it finds the control whose name is the one I need, but I think it's a very inefficient approach. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: The fact that you're in .Net 1.1, requirement or choice ? The best approach would be to update (even to 2.0 or 3.5), but it's not always possible...

Comment: Couldn't find any way to do it in the documentation of .Net 1.1...

Comment: The `Find()` method does the same under the hood: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,8db4ff0bd144aa76

Comment: It is *not* inefficient, never takes more than a few microseconds.  Just plain object references, automatically bounded by never being able to ever add more than ten thousand controls.  And of course the exact thing that Find() does.  Don't forget to recurse to find nested controls.